# The cost function and gradient of softmax classifier

Tags: machine-learning, softmax

When training a softmax classifier, I used minFunc function in **`Matlab`**, but it didn't work, the step size would reach `TolX` quickly and the accuracy is not even 5%. There must be something wrong but I just couldn't find it.

Here is my `Matlab` code about the cost function and gradient:

`z=x*W;` `%x` is the input data, it's an m*n matrix, m is the number of samples, n is the number of units in the input layer. W is an n*o matrix, o is the number of units in the output layer.

`a=sigmoid(z)./repmat(sum(sigmoid(z),2),1,o);` `%a` is the output of the classifier.

`J=-mean(sum(target.*log(a),2))+l/2*sum(sum(W.^2));` %This is the cost function, target is the desired output, it's an m*n matrix. l is the weight decay parameter.

```
Wgrad=-x'*(target-a)/m+l*W;
```

the formula can be found [here](http://deeplearning.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Softmax_Regression). Can anyone point out where my error is?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, I should not use the sigmoid function, it should simply be `exp`.

Comment: can you make your answer more clear by typing the full solution; maybe helpful for others.